# How to change color of particular grid lines of chartist chart

Tags: javascript, linechart, chartist.js

I am rendering the line chart using [Chartist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/) I am trying to change the color of particular vertical grids but I didn't find any way to do so in the plugin.

So as seen in the image, I would like to darken the 2nd and 9th vertical grid lines. (2nd and 9th is just for an example, I will be getting indexes of the grids to be highlighted dynamically from the backend.)

[image]

I am thinking to somehow do this in draw event, but not sure how to do this.

```
chart.on('draw', function (data) {
  if (data.type === 'grid') {

  }
});
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question: How did you draw the vertical cursor with the tooltip on hover? Did you use a plugin or you did it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is via CSS.  Something like this will work:

`.ct-grid.ct-horizontal:nth-of-type(2),
.ct-grid.ct-horizontal:nth-of-type(9) {
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 10px 5px;
}`

Obviously you could add a parent class and then just toggle this on the parent element if you need to turn these thicker gridlines on and off.

*NOTE* - somewhat surprisingly, chartist.js seems to add the class `ct-horizontal` to the vertical gridlines, and vice versa...

See this fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/whf5h1yu/2/

Comment: Works nicely, but do you know why it doesn't work with ct-vertical? Thanks!